# Android - Check if contact has ONLY company name

Tags: android

I want to check if a contact from my list has only a name and a company name and no other things.

```
Cursor cursor = null;
        if (Verify.notNull(email)) {
            final Uri URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(email));
            final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{Contacts.CONTACT_ID};
            try {
                cursor = cr.query(URI,
                        PROJECTION,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && !cursor.isNull(0)) {
                    return cursor.getInt(0);
                }
```

But i do not know how to get company name and then check if only both name and company name exist in the contact's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution

```
if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
        String companyName = "";
        String displayName  = "";
      // Getting Display Name

  displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));

 //Getting Organization details

 if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
 companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
  }
   if(companyName!=null && !companyName.isEmpty() && displayName!=null && !displayName .isEmpty()){

 // Here company name and name exists write your logic
   }
 }
```

For detailed Explanation please go through the link

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-contacts-content-provider-retrieving-and-listing-contacts-in-listview-example/